# jQuery collapsible block script conflicting with hover script

Tags: jquery-mobile

On my .asp site, I have a mobile version on the pages so for example the index page here http://www.paycoservices.co.uk loads a mobile version when looking on a phone, I have a hover script on the 'full site' as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
```

I am trying to add a jQuery collapsible block script which calls an external .js file, the code for this is here:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

As soon as I add the jQuery code, the collapsible block page works a treat but at the same time, no other mobile pages will load. Likewise, as soon as I remove the jQuery script, all pages load fine (even the collapsible block page but not with the collapsible effect)

Clearly there is a conflict but I've tried removing every other script from there one by one and have had no luck. Can anyone advise? Someone on the jQuery mobile forum suggested it is a bad idea mixing jQuery Mobile with other scripts which is understandable but just really like the collapsible blocks :)

I'm new to stackoverflow and tried to paste all the code into this post so you could see it but it won't accept it all. The page is here http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/tech-benefits.asp#.UWKOg78SyS0 Look at it on a mobile and it loads the mobile version.

Comment: Use jquery latest version. Also you have missed jquery mobile CSS file. Check jquerymobile.com then go to download. Use CDN hosted links and try again.

Comment: I am using the latest version according to their website? I read that an issue may be because I'm referencing jQuery more than once but if I remove one or the other it makes no difference.

Comment: Can you initialize hover script before jQuery Mobile. jQuery mobile sometimes don't work correctly if any other script (that changes DOM content somehow) is loaded after it.

Comment: In terms of css file, I saw this but wasn't sure if it was needed? So should I use all the code as stated on the jQuery site i.e.:<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Gajotres, the hover script is above the mobile script, I did try swapping round but no luck

Comment: I have added the css file however will need to host locally and edit as it doesn't use the right font I use on the site.

Comment: For now, try CDN hosted links and check if your problem is solved.

Comment: I have used CDN hosted links as above.

Comment: No sorry, what I meant was I have always used the CDN hosted links and have this issue.

Comment: I think ultimately my issue is that I am yet to find which script is conflicting with my jQuery script. If i remove the hover script completely, the issue still occurs in that all other pages don't open so I'm of the impression that the issue can't be with that script? I have been through every other script one by one and removed then tested until I see both normal pages and my jQuery page displaying correctly but nothing. Maybe my jQuery Mobile script just can't work with my current scripts?

Comment: The console in chrome flags up 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'trigger' of undefined and the link within there takes me to that script but it just lists all of it so not sure which part has the problem. I think I am in out of my depth now...

Comment: Ok, I removed every other script from the page and only left this jQueryMobile one and STILL that works ok but no other page loads. I'm totally at a loss now :(

Comment: The latest is that in an odd turn of events, I got this working by removing this line of code from my index.asp page: <script language="javascript">setPage()</script> however at the same time that messed up with the css and layout on the site so solved one problem but looking at the other one. One step at least :)